# md5 hash or simpler hash implemtation in android j2me

Tags: android, encryption, hash, bluetooth

Is there any way to encrypt data passing between two android phones in j2me?

Not to mention I am using BT as medium.

Comment: You know md5 is _barely_ suitable as a hash algo and should never, ever be used for encryption right?

Comment: Diffie-Hellman kex is pretty simply to implement, and may be used to exchange Blow/Triplefish hashes. However it may be too heavy for large amounts of data @ j2me.

Comment: How about a simple base64 encoding and decoding? does j2me have any in built techniques to do that?

Comment: Android is *not* a j2me platform. It is closer to a j2se from what I can see.

Answer (score -1):

Yes simple base64 encoding and decoding can be implemented in j2me.. use class of Base64, just google for it...

Comment: Yes Slup true, even i did not said that base64 is encryption, as i said Base64 can be used in j2me.